# Python - Inhibit creation of temporary files

Tags: python, numpy, temporary-files

I have a continuously running python process that creates temporary files that I don't know how to read.  I've tried using open with 'rb' and np.fromfile with float and int but the results don't make sense.  I am honestly not sure when Python decides to make a temporary file, but regardless, since I can't interpret the data, can I prevent creation of the files in the first place?  They fill up the hard drive and then crash the process.

**Edit:**The timing is such that I think a temp file is created every time I download a file from the internet with urllib.request.
`video, _http = urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_path)`

**Historical:** 
I think python is creating the temporary files because I ran this utility (`fnotifystat`) that tells me when a file is touched in my /tmp/ directory.

```
Total   Open  Close   Read  Write   PID  Process         Pathname
152.0    2.0    1.0    6.0  143.0  18978 python          /tmp/tmpqsj_h99n
  4.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    2.0  18978 python          /tmp/x13i7gh5

Total   Open  Close   Read  Write   PID  Process         Pathname
 32.0    0.0    0.0   32.0    0.0  18978 python          /tmp/tmpqsj_h99n
```

Comment: Is it your python program? Python doesn't create temporary files unless the code tells it to

Comment: Interesting.  There is no tempfile import anywhere in my code.  I'll update my question with the evidence I have python is creating the files.

Comment: What is the extension of the tempfile and where is it going?

Comment: no extension and to the /tmp/ folder

Comment: are you using any packages which might be making the temp files?

Comment: potentially - nothing that I am aware of though. I am using Django, Numpy, OpenCV, git, pytz, datetime, requests and a host of other imports.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208735/discussion-between-dangoodrick-and-user1558604).

Comment: Could you confirm that the process ID of your process matches that which is reported to have created the file. (Just to verify not a virus or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib.request.urlretrieve` does indeed create temporary files.
`urllib.request.urlcleanup()` removes them.